# Can you call ROW_NUMBER() in dynamic sql and use Common Table Expressions in Dynamic Sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to limit the number of records returned by calling ROW_NUMBER(), but I am curious as to if you can call it in dynamic sql?

Also, Can you use CTE's in dynamic sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean, as opposed to being called from inside a stored procedure or other code object?  If that's the question, the answer is **yes**.  Note for the record that row_number is only supported on SQL 2005 and later.